# Probability of identical twins

Tags: probability

I have this problem statement:

Suppose that in the population of twins, males and females are equally likely to occur and that the probability that  twins are identical is $\alpha$. If twins are not identical, their genes are independent.

I am supposed to show that

$$P(MM) = P(FF) = \frac{1+\alpha}{4} $$

My approach is, where $I$ is for identical and MM and FF stand for the event that, in a random pair of twins, both are male (or female):

$$P(MM) = P(MM|I)P(I) + P(MM|I^c)P(I^c)$$
$$P(MM) = P(MM|I)\alpha + P(MM|I^c)(1-\alpha) $$

By the independence clause above,

$$P(MM|I^c) = P(M)P(M) $$

And so

$$P(MM)= P(MM|I)\alpha + \frac{1-\alpha}{4} $$

Now, for the first equation to be true it must be that

$$P(MM|I) = \frac 1 2 $$

How do I show this? I don't see anything in the problem statement that would justify this.

Thanks.

Comment: You probably meant to say that $MM$ and $FF$ stand for the event that, in a random pair of twins, both are male (or female).

Comment: Yes but how does that help me to move forward?

Comment: Given that twins are identical, they can either both be male or both be female, with the probabilities being equal.

Comment: How do you know that? Maybe there's a skew?

Comment: It says "Suppose that in the population of twins, males and females are equally likely to occur"

Comment: @badmax: It helps in that it allows anyone potentially willing to help you to just focus on the question itself, as opposed to guessing details you have omitted.

Comment: @Bhoot in a population of twins yes, it doesn't say anything about a population of identical twins. Is it not possible for a skew in a population of identical twins and equal probabilities overall?

Comment: @badmax Don't you think that $\text{Identical Twins}\subset \text{Twins}$? I think the problem means for you to apply the symmetry between the sexes here.

Comment: So if property $A$ holds for all $x$,$y$ in a set $S$, it also holds for all subsets and thus holds for identical twins. Seems almost trivial in hindsight...

Answer (score 2):

Consider the given statement "If twins are not identical, their genes are independent." I would understand this to mean that among fraternal (i.e., non-identical) twins, $\frac{1}{4}$ are MM, $\frac{1}{4}$ are FF and $\frac{1}{2}$ are MF (or FM).  I think this observation is the key to finishing off the problem.

Answer (score 1):

We have
$$P(MM|I)= \frac12$$

To think about it by pure logic, it would simply mean that "Given that the genes are identical (I), the probability of having a male twins (MM) would be 1/2", which by words makes perfect sense as it's a case of either MM or FF (50:50) if the genes are identical, and never a case of MF or FM. I'm not sure if your side accepts pure words explanation (at least mine does), but if a mathematical statement is required, I suppose listing out the set of $I = \{MM, FF\}$ will help.